# How do I install Windows XP on my old laptop?

Tags: windows-xp, operating-systems, iso-image, windows-installation, bootable-media

I recently wiped/killed my old Windows Laptop (Thinkpad T40) using free disk erasing software. Now I realized the mistake of not having created a reliable image of the existing Windows XP operating system. I have a 1 GB flash drive, rufus software (downloaded from www.rufus.ie website) and a ISO image of MS Windows XP downloaded from microsoft.com (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=18242  filename is w2k3sp2_3959_usa_x64fre_spcd.iso) . However the rufus software refuses to create a bootable USD drive. Any suggestions on how to get past this hurdle?

Comment: Install GNU/Linux.

Comment: What has your research shown for this issue? What error message(s) are you getting from Rufus? What steps did you follow to attempt to create the drive?

Comment: I believe that the T40 uses a 32-bit CPU. The image you linked seems to be 64-bits Windows Server 2003. So I don't think it is what you want. Also, from my experience, even if you were to find a generic 32-bits Windows XP, it may not accept the OEM license key on the laptop's sticker, if you still have it that is.

Comment: That is not an iso for XP but rather service pack 2 for XP and cannot be used to make an install disk,  XP is not available for download from Microsoft, find a Dell XP with SP3 install disc on ebay, they are cheap since they do not come with a key. After install use your key to activate. I have several of these Dell discs and use them frequently to install XP on older hardware.

Comment: @multithr3at3d My first instinct was to go for a free linux ISO.  Apparently thinkpad t40 is a NTFS and will not allow a linux installation (from what I gathered online). I could be wrong though.

Comment: @someuser you maybe correct. I found some other 32 bit version online which seemed to be a self installation package. I was worried if it could contain a virus and as a result did not let it finish. I was not sure if my T40 was a 32 bit or a 64 bit.

Comment: @moab thank you - you maybe onto something. Do you have a trusted ebay vendor that I can use?

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Dell-Windows-XP-Pro-Professional-32-Bit-SP3-CD-Reinstallation-Disc-U317K-0R662K/143272412716?epid=1471803375&hash=item215bb3862c:g:TswAAOSw8oFc7ej6

Comment: @thecoolking no, that statement doesn't make sense. A particular computer isn't "a NTFS", NTFS is simply the type of filesystem that Windows uses (although Linux can mount it with a couple libraries installed). When you install a Linux distribution, you repartition the hard drive to use a Linux filesystem.

Comment: @moab So if I change the boot sequence to have the CD drive as #1 and have the CD in the cd drive, I should be able to install the windows OS? Do I need to do anything else (like formatting) to the hard drive prior to installing the windows OS?  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @moab so I bought the ISO file download from this guy on ebay - https://www.ebay.com/itm/253943864334?ViewItem=&item=253943864334 but now it is asking for a EULA. The vendor says it works fine for others and is offering a refund. Any suggestions on how to get past this hurdle?